# Check string format with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check a valid path, some parts of the path can be arbitrary. The path has the following format, the changeable part are called variable_1 and variable_2. How cann I check this?

```
sftp:// name[:variable_1]‌@host:port[/variable_2]‌/file
```

Comment: Is there any regex that you tried?

Comment: Just replace the variable part with `.*` to allow anything or replace them with `\w*` or may be some character class like `[^@]*` and `[^\]]*` as per your requirements

Comment: I wanted to suggest just doing `new URL("...")` and getting properties from it (ie. `url = new URL("...");` then you can get `url.username`, `url.password`, `url.hostname`, `url.port`, `url.pathname`...) but... apparently it doesn't work for `sftp://` as it just reads `sftp:` as the protocol and the whole rest as the pathname...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would need the format of the variable to be more specific:

```
new RegExp(/sftp:\/\/ name\[:variable_1\]‌@host:port\[\/variable_2\]‌\/file/)
```

Comment: regexAbov.exec("sftp://name:variable_1@host:port/variable_2/file"), returns null, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
sftp:\/\/ name:(\w+)@host:port\/(\w+)\/file
```

The `\w+` will match variable_1 and variable_2.

(I am not sure if the blank space before "name" was meant to be there or was a typo, but I kept it)